# AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am new to python and I get stuck in this error. I want to print names and years of birth of animals in team in an order by the name. Now I am keeping getting printing years and names but without order. I wanted to use lambda but than error occures. Could you help me please?

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth
        self.members = []        

    def add_member(self, member):
        self.member = member
        self.members.append(team.member)

def print_team(team):
    list_members= []
    for member in team.members:
        list_members.append(member.name)
        list_members.append(member.year_of_birth)
        print('{} ({})'.format(member.name ,member.year_of_birth) )

    print (list_members)

    for memeber in list_members:
        sorted(list_members, key = lambda member: member.name)

    print (list_members)

team = Team('Wolves')
team.add_member(Animal('Josh', 2015))
team.add_member(Animal('Quinn', 2016))
team.add_member(Animal('Peter', 2010))
print_team(team)
```

line , in 
    sorted(memberlist, key = lambda member: member.name)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Would be good to fix your code first - I think some names are in the wrong positions

Comment: What attribute? Post full error!

Comment: `list_members` is an alternating list of values (you append two attributes on each loop), not class objects.

Comment: I absolutely forgot. I am sorry. Here is edited version

Comment: Actually, what is `memberlist`? You have several incarnations of that name, with some variations,  but I can't see that one defined. There's a number of issues here, I'd suggest taking a step back and ensure each stage of your code is consistent.

Comment: check spelling e.g. memeber

Comment: And why is `year_of_birth` in the `Team` class? It should be the `Animal` class, which will also need an argument for it in its `__init__`.

Comment: Your code is throwing away the sorted list that `sorted(list_members, key = lambda member: member.name)` returns (even if it worked).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution:

In order to print an object of any class that you created, you must implement the `__str__()` method or the `__repr__()` method as an official string representation of your objects. So, here is the modified `Animal` class:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, name, year_of_birth):
        self.name = name
        self.year_of_birth = year_of_birth # Added this field because your created Animal objects had it in the example.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + str(self.year_of_birth)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + " " + str(self.year_of_birth)
```

Next thing, I simplified your `add_member()` method because there was no reason for `self.member = member`:

```
def add_member(self, member):
        self.members.append(member)
```

Next, I modified your `print_team()` function like this:

```
def print_team(team):
    list_members= []
    for member in team.members:
        list_members.append(member)

    print("Unsorted: ")
    print (list_members)

    list_members.sort(key = lambda animal: animal.name)

    print("Sorted by name: ")
    print (list_members)
```

You can simply append any object of type `Animal` in the `list_members` list. After that, you can sort your list using `sort()` and then print it. The code below:

```
team = Team('Wolves',2015)
team.add_member(Animal('Josh',2015))
team.add_member(Animal('Quinn',2145))
team.add_member(Animal('Peter',3000))
print_team(team)
```

Produces the following result:

```
Unsorted: 
[Josh 2015, Quinn 2145, Peter 3000]
Sorted by name: 
[Josh 2015, Peter 3000, Quinn 2145]
```