# 'str' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, string, attributes, attributeerror, self

I've looked through several articles on this topic but I could not figure out any way to adapt this to my scenario. I'm running this code in python3 console:

```
### API MANAGER ###

import requests, time, pandas as pd

class api_manager():
    #from ipython.display import display, HTML
    
    def __init__(self, api_identifier = 1):
        
        test_api = "570/"
        live_api = "205790/"

        self.heroes = []
        self.items = []
        self.token = ""
        self.api = ""
        self.url = "https://api.steampowered.com/"

        if api_identifier == 1:
            self.api = live_api
        else:
            self.api = test_api
        
        self.get_access_token()
        self.initialize_heroes()
        self.initialize_items()
        pass
    
    
    def get_access_token(self):
        with open("conf/access.config") as file:
            self.token = file.read().split(":")[1]
        
        file.close()
        pass
    
    
    def initialize_heroes(self):
        api_method = "IEconDOTA2_"
        response = requests.get(self.url + api_method + self.api + "GetHeroes/v1/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token)
        hero_list = response.json()
        
        for hero_id in range(len(hero_list['result']['heroes'])):
            self.heroes.append([hero_list['result']['heroes'][hero_id]['id'], hero_list['result']['heroes'][hero_id]['localized_name'], hero_list['result']['heroes'][hero_id]['name'].replace('npc_dota_hero_', "").replace("_", " ")])
        
        #self.heroes.sort()
        #heroes_df = self.pd.DataFrame(self.heroes, columns=["ID", "Hero", "Hero Tag"])
        #self.pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        
        #display(HTML(heroes_df.to_html(index = False)))
        pass
    
    
    def initialize_items(self):
        api_method = "IEconDOTA2_"
        response = requests.get(self.url + api_method + self.api + "GetGameItems/v1/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token)
        item_list = response.json()
        
        for item_id in range(len(item_list['result']['items'])):
            self.items.append([item_list['result']['items'][item_id]['id'], item_list['result']['items'][item_id]['localized_name'], item_list['result']['items'][item_id]['name']])
        
        #self.items.sort()
        #items_df = self.pd.DataFrame(self.items, columns=["ID", "Item", "Item Tag"])
        #self.pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
        
        #display(HTML(items_df.to_html(index = False)))
        pass
    
    
    def get_match_details(match_id, self):
        api_method = "IDOTA2Match_"
        response = requests.get(self.url + api_method + self.api + "GetMatchDetails/V001/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token + "&match_id=" + str(match_id))
        print(response.json())
        pass
        
        
    def get_match_details_in_range(match_id, match_id_upper_bound, self):
        api_method = "IDOTA2Match_"
        for next_match_id in range(match_id, match_id_upper_bound):
            response = requests.get(self.url + api_method + self.api + "GetMatchDetails/V001/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token + "&match_id=" + str(next_match_id))
            print(response.json())
            time.sleep(1.05)
        pass
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.url + " " + self.api
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.url + " " + self.api
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\Dropbox\DotA 2 WebAPI Development\Executable Python Files\dota_api_manager.py", line 77, in get_match_details
    response = requests.get(self.url + api_method + self.api + "GetMatchDetails/V001/?format=JSON&language=en_us&key=" + self.token + "&match_id=" + str(match_id))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'url'
```

I have tried different things like moving the import statement into the class and stuff like that and also tried implementing `__str__()` and `__repr__()` as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47621044/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute) but I couldn't get this to work. I'm fairly new to Python so it might be that there's something obvious that I just overlooked. Thanks in advance for you help and let me know if there's any additional information you could need!

Comment: You have the arguments in the wrong order: `def get_match_details(match_id, self):` The first argument is always `self`.

Comment: Same problem here: `def get_match_details_in_range(match_id, match_id_upper_bound, self):`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that self has always to be the first argument, that's really good to know. Thanks, I guess that will fix it then, I'll test it asap tomorrow.

Comment: With the way you wrote it, `match_id` is the `api_manager` object, and `self` is the string argument.

Comment: When you call a method, the object that it was called on will be the first argument. The `self` name is not special, it's just a convention.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense as long as one knows that it is a convention rather than a language specific keyword. Thanks for your detailed explanation on that matter, not everything is too intuitive in Python when coming from Java and being used to that syntax.

Comment: In most other languages the `self` or `this` argument isn't mentioned specifically in the parameter list, so it *is* a special keyword. But Python simplifies it. That's why it can be called `self` in instance methods and `cls` in class methods.